# How to find second smallest UNIQUE number in a list?

Tags: python

I need to create a function that returns the second smallest unique number, which means if
`list1 = [5,4,3,2,2,1]`, I need to return 3, because 2 is not unique.

I've tried:

```
def second(list1):
    result = sorted(list1)[1]
    return result
```

and

```
def second(list1):
    result = list(set((list1)))
    return result
```

but they all return 2.

EDIT1:

Thanks guys! I got it working using this final code:

```
def second(list1):
    b = [i for i in list1 if list1.count(i) == 1]
    b.sort()
    result = sorted(b)[1]
    return result
```

EDIT 2:

Okay guys... really confused. My Prof just told me that if `list1 = [1,1,2,3,4]`, it should return 2 because 2 is still the second smallest number, and if `list1 = [1,2,2,3,4]`, it should return 3.
Code in eidt1 wont work if `list1 = [1,1,2,3,4]`.
I think I need to do something like:

if duplicate number in position list1[0], then remove all duplicates and return second number. 
Else if duplicate number postion not in list1[0], then just use the code in EDIT1.

Comment: What did you try to determine whether a number was unique?

Comment: My second try was to eliminate the duplicate items in a list.... then from there I know I can use `sorted(list1)[2]` to return 3. However, I need to write a general code where the list could be [5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1] and I need to return 5 but I can't use the sorted() because I won't know what to put in the square bracket. (sorted(list1)[???])

Comment: `set(list1)` does not remove values that appear more than once. `{3,4,4} => {3,4}`, not `{3}`.

Comment: You are sorting twice. Once with `b.sort` and the 2nd time with `sorted(b)`

Answer (score 3):

Without using anything fancy, why not just get a list of uniques, sort it, and get the second list item?

```
a = [5,4,3,2,2,1] #second smallest is 3
b = [i for i in a if a.count(i) == 1]
b.sort()
>>>b[1]
3


a = [5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1] #second smallest is 5
b = [i for i in a if a.count(i) == 1]
b.sort()
>>> b[1]
5
```

Obviously you should test that your list has at least two unique numbers in it.  In other words, make sure `b` has a length of at least 2.

Comment: Hey thanks! I used your code and got the result I need after adding some lines

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove non unique elements - use `sort`/[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) or [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
2. <strike>Use min - O(n) to determine the minimum instead of `sort` - O(nlongn). (In any case if you are using `groupby` the data is already sorted)</strike> I missed the fact that OP wanted the second minimum, so sorting is still a better option here

**Sample Code**

*Using Counter*

```
>>> sorted(k for k, v in Counter(list1).items() if v == 1)[1]
1
```

*Using Itertools*

```
>>> sorted(k for k, g in groupby(sorted(list1)) if len(list(g)) == 1)[1]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here usage of `set()` on a list is not going to help. It doesn't purge the duplicated elements. What I mean is :

```
l1=[5,4,3,2,2,1]
print set(l1)
```

Prints

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here, you're not removing the duplicated elements, but the list gets unique

In your example you want to remove all duplicated elements. 
Try something like this.

```
l1=[5,4,3,2,2,1]
newlist=[]
for i in l1:
    if l1.count(i)==1:
    newlist.append(i)
print newlist
```

This in this example prints

```
[5, 4, 3, 1]
```

then you can use `heapq` to get your second largest number in your list, like this

```
print heapq.nsmallest(2, newlist)[-1]
```

Imports : `import heapq`, The above snippet prints `3` for you. 
This should to the trick. Cheers!

Comment: I like the idea of using `heapq`, but you've negated any algorithmic advantages your solution had by using `l1.count()` instead of a data-structure suitable for doing the counting in O(N) time (e.g. `collections.Counter`), or even O(NlogN) (`itertools.groupby` + `sort`).  Using `l1.count()` makes this an O(N^2) algorithm :-).

Comment: Yeah, could have used Collections which gives out better performance. Will use them next time. Thanks for the guidance @mgilson!

Comment: Who is this "everyone" in "Okay, everyone says use a set() on a list"?  Nobody suggested using set() to get the uniques.

Comment: @BlivetWidget What I meant by everyone is that if you google for removing duplicates or purging duplicates 7/10 people have suggested the usage of `set()` function. By that way here no one has suggested that! I'll change it here anyway! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancier approach that doesn't use count (which means it should have significantly better performance on large datasets).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def getUnique(data):
    dd = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for value in data:
        dd[value] += 1
    result = [key for key in dd.keys() if dd[key] == 1]
    result.sort()
    return result

a = [5,4,3,2,2,1]
b = getUnique(a)
print(b)
# [1, 3, 4, 5]
print(b[1])
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys! I got the working code thanks to all your help and helping me to think on the right track. This code works:

```
`def second(list1):
    if len(list1)!= len(set(list1)):
         result = sorted(list1)[2]
        return result
    elif len(list1) == len(set(list1)):
        result = sorted(list1)[1]
        return result`
```